# fetch file data from ftp & process in php

Tags: php, csv, ftp

I have the below script to import data from a csv file on my ftp server, the script works correctly.

```
$ftp_server = '---Domain---';
$ftp_user_name = '---Uname---';
$ftp_user_pass = '---pass---';

// open some file for reading
$csvfile = '/home/domain/public_html/myfolder/user.csv';

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) 
{
  echo "File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.\n";
  exit;
}
else
{
   echo "File exist on this  path.\n";
}
```

**user.csv**

```
Email          Fname    lname
------------------------------
mark@gmail.com  mark    martin
allan@gmail.com allan   lee
```

I want to fetch data from csv file & pass to php function which will process that data with DB

i.e. add-update user information

I am not getting how to fetch data & pass to function

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a=array();
$file = fopen('user.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  array_push($a,$line);
}
fclose($file);
```

//you will get all the content in array $a, you can ride array by using foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$csvfile = '/home/domain/public_html/myfolder/user.csv';

if (($handle = fopen($csvfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // do whatever processing you need with $line array
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This solution will give you csv data line by line. If you need all data from csv to an array Use @user1844933's solution